# If and only if equivalent to logic AND ? Example with two basic geometry theorems

Tags: geometry, logic, first-order-logic

I was wondering if these two things :

- $\iff$
- AND

were the same?

My wondering came because I was studying the theorem that says that "if $2$ lines are parallel, then any line perpendicular to one is perpendicular to the other" and the theorem that says that "if $2$ lines are perpendicular to  the same line, then they are parallel". I am convinced these two theorems are converse each one with the other. But I might be wrong?

Based on that (which might be wrong), I started studying and comparing :

1. "any line perpendicular to one is perpendicular to the other"
2. "if $2$ lines are perpendicular to the same line"

Turns out that (according to me),
$(1)$ is the same as saying $$d_1 \bot d \iff d_2\bot d$$
and $(2)$ is the same as saying $$d_1 \bot d \land d_2\bot d$$

where $\land$ is the logic AND.

Hence my question.

Comment: In your example, the first $\iff$ statement is True when neither is perpendicular to the given line, but the second $\land$ statement is False.  So no, they are not equivalent

Comment: $A\iff B$ is the same as $(A\land B)\lor (\lnot A\land \lnot B).$ So, no, it is not the same as $A\land B.$

Comment: Ok, then should I deduce the two theorems are not converse one with each other as well?

Comment: Those theorems use [quantifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic)) in different ways, so they're not simply converses of each other.

Comment: Aaah I think I got it, in the first theorem, if $2$ lines are parallel, then we can deduce (even if it's not in the theorem) that any line that forms a $20°$ angle with one, forms a $20°$ angle with the other one. Whereas in the second theorem, we can not get away from the $90°$ case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Written in full, your conjectures are:

> If $2$ lines are parallel, then any line perpendicular to one is perpendicular to the other

$$l_1 || l_2 \implies l\bot l_1 \land l\bot l_2$$

and

> If $2$ lines are perpendicular to the same line, then they are parallel

$$l_1\bot l \land l_2\bot l_ \implies l_1 || l_2$$

and you are trying to prove that:

$$l_1\bot l \land l_2\bot l_ \iff l_1 || l_2$$

However, there is not enough information here to deduce this.

In fact, we have for the first conjecture:

$$l_1 || l_2 \implies (l\bot l_1 \land l\bot l_2) \lor (l\not\bot l_1 \land l\not\bot l_2)$$

which can also be written:

$$l_1 || l_2 \implies (l\bot l_1 \iff l\bot l_2)$$

Answer (score 0):

I think it is hard to dispute the claim that $1+1=3$ *if and only if* $1+1=3$

But would you agree with the claim that $1+1=3$ *and* $1+1=3$?